# Error Handling in Jersey Restful API

Tags: json, api, rest, jersey

I have a method in Jersey Servlet

```
@POST
@Path("{type}:{bank_code}/accounts/{account}")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Produces("application/json")
public String VerifyRecipient(MultivaluedMap<String,String> requestParamsPost,
        @PathParam("type") String type,
        @PathParam("bank_code") String bank_code,
        @PathParam("account") String account) {
    String ret=null;
    Integer trxn_type_id=null;
    this.logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    if(account==null){
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(
                Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).type(
                MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).entity(
                "Account is not found").build());

    }
```

If somebody is not giving any value for {account} I want to return a 404 not found JSON response. But my problem is when there is no value for {account} the request is not even reaching my method. IS there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Your example is actually hitting a different URL - `{type}:{bank_code}/accounts` rather than `{type}:{bank_code}/accounts/{account}`. If you do want some bespoke behaviour for this you'll have to create a different method with this as the `@Path` annotation.